# Flutter: FlareActor Delay in showing

Tags: flutter, flare

```
    Widget CustomBottomBar(BuildContext context)  {

    return Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: IgnorePointer(
        child: Stack(
          //alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: new FlareActor("assets/robot.flr", alignment: Alignment.center, fit: BoxFit.contain, animation: "buscando",),
              ),
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

My little Actor takes 1-2 seconds to show up, can I do some coding to show another Flutter's own while this example loads a CircularProgressIndicator, if so, how can I do it?

Comment: can you please show the rive(Flare) link for the animation you made.

Comment: https://rive.app/a/kios19/files/flare/robo/preview

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Add a little animation before showing the FlareActor

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Can you elaborate a bit further on how / if you fixed it?